# After updating Visual Studio extension from 2019 to 2022, error occurs when uninstalling extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

I have a simple Visual Studio extension which was developed for 2019. After updating the extension to 2022, it installs fine but after uninstalling, I encounter error pop-ups when launching Visual Studio 2022 again.

[image]

[image]

After that, when I check the extension manager again, it shows that there are no extensions installed (which is not the case). Something seems to have gone wrong with the list:

[image]

As for the steps in updating to 2022, I followed what was described here under ["What Needs to be Changed"](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/migrate-vsix-to-vs2022/) and recompiled using VS2022.

The extension still works after installing, the issue happens after I uninstall it.

This is how the manifest file looks like:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I just did these steps:
Visual Studio Installer -> repair VS2022 -> recover from the error

Create an empty VSIX using VS2022 VSIX template (no code was added by me, it is completely default). I now have a clean VS2022 install, extensions are ok and no error pop-ups. Once i install this empty VSIX extension, the problem occurs.

Comment: As you did, I run "repair", and everything was fine for a few minutes. Then, I just opened the extensions list, and hit "update" on one that was available, "ml.net model bulder" provided by Mictrosoft by default in the installation.  After that, it crashed again!  Looks like any VSIX install can crash Visual Studio since a few days!!

Answer (score 1):

We had almost the same issue, when installing or updating any vsix package, VS2022 completely crash and was impossible to use.

They just released the version 17.2.5 and the bug is now fixed.